# Show loader while waiting asynchronous response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i don't know how to show a loader while i'm waiting for a response by a funtion written in javascript.

I have one `<div>` which contain the response:

```
<input type="button" name="btn-s" value="Search">
<div align="center" id="div_feed_data">
</div>
```

and in the same page i call that function:

```
function get_feed_data(id_feed,not_add)
{
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)    {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
     else    {
    // code for IE6, IE5
      var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
     document.getElementById("div_feed_data").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;   //NELL' ELEMENTO CON QUESTO ID VIENE MOSTRATO IL RISULTATO MANDATO DAL SERVER

    }
    }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","libraries/show_feed_data.php?id_feed="+id_feed+"&not_add="+not_add,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

Now i'd like to place a loader gif instead of the button until the response is ready, but i don't know how to do because i've found just method for pure ajax code and i'm not good in js as in english, so i need an help, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://fontawesome.io/examples/#animated

```
function get_feed_data(id_feed,not_add)
{
    $('#myIcon').fadeIn();
    ...
    ...
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
       // request is complete
       $('#myIcon').fadeOut();
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create an Ajax request, it will go through the following states.

```
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready
```

When you trigger .send() method these states will processed. So you try to **show** **the loader gif** **as soon as you call the Ajax** call and **when the ready state is 4 you can hide the loader.**

**pseudo code**

```
function yourFunction() {
   //call the show loader function here
   if(xmlReq.readyState == 4 && smlReq.status == 200){
        //call the hide loader function here
   }
}
```

Note : You can even show the messages for each states based on the readystate value.

**pseudo code**

```
function yourFunction() {
   if(xmlReq.readyState == 1 ){
        //call the show loader function here
        //console.log('connected');
   }

   if(xmlReq.readyState == 2 ){
        //call the show loader function here
        //console.log('Request Received');
   }

    if(xmlReq.readyState == 3 ){
        //call the show loader function here
        //console.log('Processing');
   }

   if(xmlReq.readyState == 4 && xmlReq.status == 200){
        //call the hide loader function here
   }
}
```

Comment: This is more accurate so i think it can help better other people too, just for thati chose this answer as correct. But the one of MachProgramAlot is correct too.